# dual boot Ubuntu 22.04 not working properly

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 22.04, freeze, asus

I have installed Ubuntu22.04 in a laptop where I already had Windows10 preinstalled. It all seemed to be working properly, I even managed to install ROS (I needed it for a robotics project). However, the next day problems have been arising in general:

- Firefox takes a lot of time to load, and most of the times it just does not start up.
- The wifi does not connect and whenever I open the settings, wifi's section does not appear. Instead, a message appears in the network section saying that network-manager should be running. However, if i check the network-manager in the terminal it says (using service network-manager state) it says that it is running)
- Sometimes settings does not start up either.
- The `$ sudo` command does not responde and the terminal gets frozen.
- And now, when powering off so as to restart the computer, it has got stuck in this screen:

[image: Screen where it got frozen when powering off]

- All programs (except the terminal) tend to freeze.

I do not know a lot about neither ubuntu, nor dual booting, and my computer's specs are the next:

- Laptop: Vivobook_ASUS X3500PC_K3500PC
- CPU: 11th gen Intel Core i5-11300H
- Installed RAM: 16GB
- GPU1: Intel Iris Xe Graphics
- GPU2: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050
- Disk: NVMe Intel SSDPEKNU512GZ
- Partition where Ubuntu is installed: 100GB

Comment: Have you installed the correct nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository? Did you update UEFI to latest available and SSD firmware to latest available?

Comment: No i haven't, I will try and tell you how it worked. However, it seems to be a problem relationed to firefox, as everything works fine whenever the firefox browser is not running. I have been searching and people with Ubuntu 20.04 tend to have problems with it being a snap and not a "normal" package.

Comment: If you want to use Firefox as .deb not snap. You had to add ppa and change priority of install, so snap is not reinstalled. Steps to copy (which is what I did). https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04